# Change Latex root file in VS Code with Plugin Latex Workshop

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, vscode-extensions

I'm stuck in a problem I don't know how to find a solution to this. So the problem is that, when compiling the Latex project in VSCode via LatexWorksop Plugin it takes the wrong **.tex** file as a root file. In the overleaf website you can select the main file in the menu. How can this be selected in VS Code?

[image: Repo Foto with main and config file]

So please ask me if you need more information about it.

I added log file

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.9.7)  18 APR 2023 14:05
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**h:/BA_Capabilities_of_OpenSource_Cloud_Computing/dsg-thesis-en/includes/config.tex
(h:/BA_Capabilities_of_OpenSource_Cloud_Computing/dsg-thesis-en/includes/config.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2022-08-30> (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks16
\inpenc@posthook=\toks17
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty
Package: fancyhdr 2022/05/18 v4.0.3 Extensive control of page headers and footers
\f@nch@headwidth=\skip49
\f@nch@O@elh=\skip50
\f@nch@O@erh=\skip51
\f@nch@O@olh=\skip52
\f@nch@O@orh=\skip53
\f@nch@O@elf=\skip54
\f@nch@O@erf=\skip55
\f@nch@O@olf=\skip56
\f@nch@O@orf=\skip57
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ae/ae.sty
Package: ae 2001/02/12 1.3 Almost European Computer Modern
 (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks18
)
\lst@mode=\count193
\lst@gtempboxa=\box51
\lst@token=\toks19
\lst@length=\count194
\lst@currlwidth=\dimen139
\lst@column=\count195
\lst@pos=\count196
\lst@lostspace=\dimen140
\lst@width=\dimen141
\lst@newlines=\count197
\lst@lineno=\count198
\lst@maxwidth=\dimen142
 (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty
File: lstmisc.sty 2020/03/24 1.8d (Carsten Heinz)
\c@lstnumber=\count199
\lst@skipnumbers=\count266
\lst@framebox=\box52
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg
File: listings.cfg 2020/03/24 1.8d listings configuration
))
Package: listings 2020/03/24 1.8d (Carsten Heinz)
 (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
Package: color 2022/01/06 v1.3d Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
 (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package color Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 149.
 (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig.sty
\wrapoverhang=\dimen143
\WF@size=\dimen144
\c@WF@wrappedlines=\count267
\WF@box=\box53
\WF@everypar=\toks20
Package: wrapfig 2003/01/31  v 3.6
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/acronym/acronym.sty
Package: acronym 2020/04/17 v1.47 Support for acronyms (Tobias Oetiker)
 (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bigfoot/suffix.sty
Package: suffix 2006/07/15 1.5a Variant command support
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex
\integerpart=\count268
\decimalpart=\count269
)
Package: xstring 2021/07/21 v1.84 String manipulations (CT)
)
\AC@clearlist=\toks21
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2022-06-20 v7.00s Hypertext links for LaTeX
 (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
 (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2022-05-17 v2.50 Cross-referencing by name of section
 (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
 (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2022-06-15 v3.15 Key value format for package options (HO)
))
\c@section@level=\count270
)
\@linkdim=\dimen145
\Hy@linkcounter=\count271
\Hy@pagecounter=\count272
 (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2022-06-20 v7.00s Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count273
 (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2022-06-20 v7.00s Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PU ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PU
)
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4162.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4167.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4170.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4177.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4182.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4408.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count274
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4746.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen146
 (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
 (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count275
\Field@Width=\dimen147
\Fld@charsize=\dimen148
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6024.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6029.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6032.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6039.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6044.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6049.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6054.
 (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count276
\c@Item=\count277
\c@Hfootnote=\count278
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.
 (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2022-06-20 v7.00s Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
 (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atveryend package
with kernel methods
)
\Fld@listcount=\count279
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count280
 (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2022-07-10 v1.10 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
 (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 285.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip58
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
 (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
 (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen149
\Gin@req@width=\dimen150
))
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...Computing/dsg-thesis-en/includes/config.tex
                                                  
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 9822 strings out of 475075
 151285 string characters out of 5783002
 487481 words of memory out of 5000000
 31136 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 470321 words of font info for 30 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 72i,0n,77p,499b,262s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have the line `\documentclass{}` in your config file. This line needs to be in the main .tex file for VScode to determine the root file. Hope this helps!